# Correct attribute types of abstract class implementation

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-typing

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm still finding the good way to describe my case. Basically, I want to inherit from an abstract class that takes another abstract class as argument, but how can I make the attributes of its implementation recognized correctly its argument types?

Is it confusing? Here is what I mean:

```py
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass


# Define abstract classes
class Params(ABC):
    """An abstract class for storing parameters."""

    pass


class Solver(ABC):
    """An abstract class to solve a problem with a specific parameter set."""

    def __init__(self, params: Params) -> None:
        """Initialize with a Params object."""
        self.params = params

    @abstractmethod
    def solve(self) -> None:
        """An abstract method that must be implemented in the subclasses."""
        pass


# Implementation of abstract classes
@dataclass
class ParamsX(Params):
    """A subclass of Params which has attributes first_param and second_param."""

    first_param: int
    second_param: list[float]


class SolverX(Solver):
    """A subclass of Solver which solve the problem X."""

    def __init__(self, params: ParamsX) -> None:
        """Initialize with the ParamsX object."""
        super().__init__(params)

    def solve(self) -> None:
        """Solve the problem X."""
        print(self.params)  # The params is recognized as Params
        print(self.params.first_param)  # The first_param is recognized as Any
        print(self.params.second_param)  # The second_param is recognized as Any


# There're also ParamsY and SolverY, ParamsZ and SolverZ, etc
```

**My question**: How can I make the `first_param` and `second_param` show respectively as the `int` and `list[float]` types? I haven't check with `mypy` but [the *Visual Studio Code* indicates that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTrZU.png).

**An attempt**:

If I do with the following code, the types are correct but I don't think it's a pythonic way, it will be like the abstract class `Params` doesn't have any purpose at all.

```py
class SolverX(Solver):
    """A subclass of Solver which takes a ParamsX object as argument."""

    def __init__(self, params: ParamsX) -> None:
        super().__init__(params)
        self.params: ParamsX  # Forced annotation
```

Comment: Note, `Params` isn't actually abstract. A class has to actually have abstract methods to be abstract.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think you're right, there are actually more attributes and methods in the `Params` in my real code, I've just simplify it to fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to [TeamSpen210](https://github.com/TeamSpen210) who gave me this answer:

> What you need is a `Generic`, not necessarily an `ABC`.
>
> Change `Solver` to be like this:
>
> ```py
> ParamT = TypeVar('ParamT', bound=Params)
>
> class Solver(ABC, Generic[ParamT]):
>     def __init__(self, param: ParamT) -> None:
>         self.params = param
>
> class SolverX(Solver[ParamsX]):
>     ....
> ```
>
> `TypeVar` defines a type variable, which you later substitute with a specific type, bound restricts it to only permit subclasses of the specified type. Then having the class "subclass" `Generic` means that the variable is scoped to the whole class. So then when you use the subscripted version, it's as if the type variable was replaced by the real class.
>
> Note the other way you can use it is specific to a function - you put it in the signature, then it takes on whatever type you use to call the function.
>
> The *MyPy* docs have a lot more info about how things work, as well as say **PEP484**:
> https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html
>
> There's also *typeshed*, the type definitions for the standard library:
> https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stdlib

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying variables on the class level:

```
class SolverX(Solver):
    """A subclass of Solver which solves the problem X."""
    params: ParamsX

    def __init__(self, params: ParamsX) -> None:
        """Initialize with the ParamsX object."""
        super().__init__(params)
```

Comment: Looks like I still have to put a line to "redirect" the type in each concrete class. I've just got an answer from a guy here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778514/14369524. It's perfectly solve my problem. Can you have a look and improve it?